# Editing posted form data using jquery/php

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have a basic form that posts textarea content to the same page. I have that working but I'm trying to get the posted content back into the form, however the textareas disappear after you submit it. This probably sounds bizarre.

`<p><?php echo ''.nl2br($_POST['textbox2']); ?></p>`

how can i press a button like "edit" and take that $_POST data and put it back into the textarea that it came from.

Any help for this crazy problem I'm having would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please provide the code, html, java script in question. Your question without any code will be very hard for other developers to answer your question. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the variable declared in your php code you can add it into the `textarea` as follows:

```
<?php
$text = $_POST['formText'];
?>

<form>
<textarea name="formText">
    <?php echo $text;?>
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

A working example is here: http://www.phlume.com/chad/testtest/test.php

Comment: I can get that to work fine, however as i said the textarea is generated from a button, so once the form submits and the page refreshes, those textareas vanish. They are in an array and are uniquely identified to display the different content, its just getting them to show up with the same content.
im no doubt making it harder than it needs to be ha.

Comment: even though the text areas disappear, they should still be declared within the $POST variable that you defined in the first place. Can't you just call that variable again? I guess I'm confused?

Comment: they might be able to, but i'm only a beginner so it's all pretty much chinese to me. I am trying to crack this though, who doesn't love a challenge?
{    var i = $('textarea').size() + 1;
     
    $('.addbox').click(function() {
        $('<textarea class="styled field" name="textbox'+ i + '">' + "<?php echo($_POST['textbox']); ?>" +'</textarea').fadeIn('fast').appendTo('.inputs');
        i++;
    });}

is what i almost have. does it make more sense yet?

Answer (score 0):

check this out: http://php.net/ternary#example-123 and here's my example:

```
<?php
$textbox2 = isset($_POST['textbox2']) ? $_POST['textbox2'] : '';
?>

<input type="text" name="textbox2" value="<?php echo $textbox2; ?>" />
```